# ¿Alguien que me apoye en la estructura de mi codigo?

Tags: c

tengo un problema con mi codigo, lo que pasa es que no se bien como formularlo, intente de esta forma pero me marca error en ciertas partes que la verdad no logro entender porque, pueden ayudarme en ver que estoy haciendo mal? O si pueden ver como puedo desarrollarlo, porque siento que me estoy extendiendo mucho (debo contener switch, no if anidados), este es el planteamiento del problema:

Desarrollar un programa capaz de calcular el total a pagar en una visita al cine dependiendo del tipo de sala seleccionada, la edad del cliente, sus compras en la dulcería y si cuenta con membresía. Las opciones para tipo de sala serán normal, premium y 3D, donde el precio por un boleto de cada sala es de $35, $50 y $60 respectivamente. Si la edad del cliente es menor a 18 o mayor a 40 se le aplicara un descuento del boleto de $5. El cliente puede elegir comprar palomitas o no, si elige comprar palomitas podrá escoger entre chicas $40, medianas $50 o grandes $60. Si el cliente cuenta con membresía se le descontaran $5 del total. Imprimir en pantalla un reporte con la descripción y los montos por cada opción seleccionada y el total de la compra.

Y este es el codigo (esta incompleto, por lo mismo que no se como puedo continuar):

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main (){
int edad, palom, boleto, total;
char sala, memb;

printf("De acuerdo a la letra, seleccione el tipo de sala:\nA) Sala Normal\nB) Sala Premium\nC) Sala 3D\n");
scanf(" %c",&sala);
printf("De acuerdo a la letra, seleccione que palomitas quiere:\nA- Palomitas Chicas\nB- Palomitas Medianas\nC- Palomitas Grandes\nD- No quiero palomitas\n");
scanf(" %c",&palom);
printf("Introduzca su edad:\n");
scanf("%d",&edad);
printf("Cuenta con membresia?:\n1- Si\n2- No\n");
scanf("%d",&memb);

switch(sala){
    case 'A':
        switch(palom){
            case 'A':
                switch(memb){
                    case 1:
                        if(edad<18 && edad>40){
                            boleto: 35-5;
                            total:boleto+40-5;
                            printf("\nSala seleccionada: Normal\n");
                            printf("Palomitas seleccionadas: Chicas\n");
                            printf("Edad: %d\n",edad);
                            printf("Membresia: Si\n");
                            printf("El costo total es: %d",total);
                        } else {
                            boleto: 35;
                            total:boleto+40-5;
                            printf("\nSala seleccionada: Normal\n");
                            printf("Palomitas seleccionadas: Chicas\n");
                            printf("Edad: %d\n",edad);
                            printf("Membresia: Si\n");
                            printf("El costo total es: %d",total);
                        }
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        if(edad<18 && edad>40){
                            boleto: 35-5;
                            total:boleto+40;
                            printf("\nSala seleccionada: Normal\n");
                            printf("Palomitas seleccionadas: Chicas\n");
                            printf("Edad: %d\n",edad);
                            printf("Membresia: No\n");
                            printf("El costo total es: %d",total);
                        } else {
                            boleto: 35;
                            total:boleto+40;
                            printf("\nSala seleccionada: Normal\n");
                            printf("Palomitas seleccionadas: Chicas\n");
                            printf("Edad: %d\n",edad);
                            printf("Membresia: No\n");
                            printf("El costo total es: %d",total);
                        }
                        break;
                }

            break;

        }

    break;
}
```

Comment: Primero, aprende lo que son las funciones, te va a simplificar mucho el codigo. Seugndo, que se supone que quieres hacer con `boleto: 35-5;`? No sera `boleto = 35-5`?

Comment: En C, como en muchos lenguajes, se asigna con `=`.

Comment: Consejo: No pongas condiciones imposibles: `if(edad<18 && edad>40)` un número no puede cumplir dos requisitos si éstos son incompatibles: ser menor de 18 y mayor de 40

Answer (score 0):

Buen día,

Creo que hay varios problemas de concepto en tu código, intentaré explicar cada uno:

1. En tus `scanf()` estas utilizando tipos de variable incorrectos, `%c` que es para variables tipo `char` lo estás utilizando con `palom` que es de tipo `int`; y `%d` que es para variables tipo `int` lo estás utilizando con `memb` que es de tipo `char` (Si no sabes la diferencia entre tipos de variables te recomiendo leer [este artículo](https://unipython.com/variables-tipos-variables-en-c/))
2. En `palom` que es de tipo `int` pides que el usuario ingrese una letra (`char`), debes cambiar el tipo de variable o indicar al usuario que ingrese un número
3. En varias partes de tu código estas utilizando `:` para intentar asignar valores. Por ejemplo `boleto: 35-5`. Para asignar un valor a una variable se utiliza `=`. Te recomiendo leer [este artículo](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anexo:Operadores_de_C_y_C%2B%2B) para reforsar el conocimiento sobre operadores en c.
4. Te hace falta un corchete para el `main` (Esto podría ser un error al copiar y pegar el código a Stack Overflow)
5. Tanto en el `switch` de `sala` como en el de `palom` solo tienen definido el `case` para `A`

Corrigiendo los puntos anteriores tu programa va a compilar, va a permitir que el usuario ingrese los datos y que tengan el tipo correcto de variable.

Ahora, para simplificar tu código lo que puedes hacer es un `switch` para cada variable que solicitas pero en lugar de ponerlos uno adentro del otro los puedes separar

En este momento estás intentando poner todas las opciones en cada uno de los `case`y tendrías que cubrir todas las combinaciones, ejemplo (Lo pongo con el editor de código para que sea fácil de leer):

```
Sala:
    Opción A:
        Palomitas:
            Opción A:
                Membresia:
                    Opción 1:
                        Edad:
                            Rango 1:
                            Rango 2:
                    Opción 2:
                        Edad:
                            Rango 1:
                            Rango 2:
            Opción B:
                Membresia:
                    Opción 1:
                        Edad:
                            Rango 1:
                            Rango 2:
                    Opción 2:
                        Edad:
                            Rango 1:
                            Rango 2:
            Opción C:
                Membresia:
                    Opción 1:
                        Edad:
                            Rango 1:
                            Rango 2:
                    Opción 2:
                        Edad:
                            Rango 1:
                            Rango 2:
            Opción D:
                Membresia:
                    Opción 1:
                        Edad:
                            Rango 1:
                            Rango 2:
                    Opción 2:
                        Edad:
                            Rango 1:
                            Rango 2:
    Opción B:
        Palomitas:
            Opción A:
                Membresia:
                    Opción 1:
                        Edad:
                            Rango 1:
                            Rango 2:
                    Opción 2:
                        Edad:
                            Rango 1:
                            Rango 2:
            Opción B:
                Membresia:
                    Opción 1:
                        Edad:
                            Rango 1:
                            Rango 2:
                    Opción 2:
                        Edad:
                            Rango 1:
                            Rango 2:
            Opción C:
                Membresia:
                    Opción 1:
                        Edad:
                            Rango 1:
                            Rango 2:
                    Opción 2:
                        Edad:
                            Rango 1:
                            Rango 2:
            Opción D:
                Membresia:
                    Opción 1:
                        Edad:
                            Rango 1:
                            Rango 2:
                    Opción 2:
                        Edad:
                            Rango 1:
                            Rango 2:
    Opción C:
        Palomitas:
            Opción A:
                Membresia:
                    Opción 1:
                        Edad:
                            Rango 1:
                            Rango 2:
                    Opción 2:
                        Edad:
                            Rango 1:
                            Rango 2:
            Opción B:
                Membresia:
                    Opción 1:
                        Edad:
                            Rango 1:
                            Rango 2:
                    Opción 2:
                        Edad:
                            Rango 1:
                            Rango 2:
            Opción C:
                Membresia:
                    Opción 1:
                        Edad:
                            Rango 1:
                            Rango 2:
                    Opción 2:
                        Edad:
                            Rango 1:
                            Rango 2:
            Opción D:
                Membresia:
                    Opción 1:
                        Edad:
                            Rango 1:
                            Rango 2:
                    Opción 2:
                        Edad:
                            Rango 1:
                            Rango 2:
```

Es mucho más fácil y legible si separamos los `switch` de forma individual y en cada `switch` agregas el precio al total y agregas una variable para guardar la selección

Te dejo un ejemplo únicamente con `sala` y `palom` funcionando, intenta hacer por tu cuenta `edad` y `membresia` para reforsar lo aprendido

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main (){
    int edad, boleto, total = 0;
    char sala, memb, palom;
    char seleccionSala[10], seleccionPalomitas[10], seleccionMembresia[5];

    printf("De acuerdo a la letra, seleccione el tipo de sala:\nA) Sala Normal\nB) Sala Premium\nC) Sala 3D\n");
    scanf(" %c", &sala);
    printf("De acuerdo a la letra, seleccione que palomitas quiere:\nA- Palomitas Chicas\nB- Palomitas Medianas\nC- Palomitas Grandes\nD- No quiero palomitas\n");
    scanf(" %c", &palom);
    printf("Introduzca su edad:\n");
    scanf(" %d", &edad);
    printf("Cuenta con membresia?:\n1- Si\n2- No\n");
    scanf(" %c", &memb);

    switch(sala){
        case 'A':
            strcpy(seleccionSala, "Normal");
            total += 35;
            break;
        
        case 'B':
            strcpy(seleccionSala, "Premium");
            total += 50;
            break;
            
        case 'C':
            strcpy(seleccionSala, "3D");
            total += 60;
            break;
    }

    switch(palom){
        case 'A':
            strcpy(seleccionPalomitas, "Chicas");
            total += 40;
            break;
        
        case 'B':
            strcpy(seleccionPalomitas, "Medianas");
            total += 50;
            break;
            
        case 'C':
            strcpy(seleccionPalomitas, "Grandes");
            total += 60;
            break;
        
        case 'D':
            strcpy(seleccionPalomitas, "No");
            total += 0;
            break;
    }

        printf("Sala seleccionada: %s\n", seleccionSala);
        printf("Palomitas seleccionadas: %s\n", seleccionPalomitas);
        printf("Edad: %d\n",edad);
        printf("Membresia: No\n");
        printf("El costo total es: %d",total);
}
```